# Upgrade Postgres 8.3 to 8.4 using Ports (on FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, port, postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade PostgreSQL 8.3 to 8.4 using Ports on FreeBSD (7.2). I found a few good guides, such as [this one](http://www.freebsddiary.org/postgresql-upgrading.php), but they won't work.

Upon running 'portupgrade -o databases/postgresql84-client postgresql-client' I get nothing. Not even an error. (I dropped the -f, since I already have the latest 8.3-client installed.)

Anyone care to offer a solution?

Answer (score 1):

That looks good to me.  Can you run the following just to make certain of your installed version?

`pkg_info -I postgresql\*`